# How to find check only first index in each split string?

Tags: python, string, indexing, split

I am trying to create define a function that:

1. Splits a string called text at every new line (ex text="1\n2\n\3)
2. Checks ONLY the first index in each of the individual split items to see if number is 0-9.
3. Return any index that has 0-9, it can be more than one line

ex: `count_digit_leading_lines  ("AAA\n1st") → 1        # 2nd line  starts  w/ digit`   1

So far my code is looking like this but I can't figure out how to get it to only check the first index in each split string:

```
def count_digit_leading_lines(text):
   for line in range(len(text.split('\n'))):
      for index, line in enumerate(line):
        if 0<=num<=9:
            return index
```

It accepts the arguement text, it iterates over each individual line (new split strings,) I think it goes in to check only the first index but this is where I get lost...

Comment: You can't simply return the index if you expect to return EACH index that as 0-9. You need some kind of data structure to store that in. Can you provide an example output of what you'd like to see given an example input?

Comment: I don't need to return every index that has 0-9, just need it to check the first index in every line. Ex: text=("ABC\n123\n456") then it becomes split as "ABC" "123" "456" it would have to go into each new thing and check index 0. A is not 0-9 don't return that, 1 is return that, 4 is return that. Output would then be line 2 and 3  because they both had first index 0-9

Comment: I understand that. But I can't quite get which output you'd like to see. A list, a dict, what?

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. I need to return an integer. No lists, dictionary, etc. Just an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code should be as simple as :

```
text=text.strip()              #strip all whitespace  : for cases ending with '\n' or having two '\n' together
text=text.replace('\t','')     #for cases with '\t' etc

s=text.split('\n')             #Split each sentence (@ '\n')

#s=[words.strip() for words in s]      #can also use this instead of replace('\t')

for i,sentence in enumerate(s):
    char=sentence[0]        #get first char in each sentence
    if char.isdigit():      #if 1st char is a digit (0-9)
        return i
```

---

**UPDATE:**
Just noticed OP's comment on another answer stating you don't want to use `enumerate` in your code (though its good practice to use enumeration). So the `for` loop modified version ***without enumerate*** is :

```
for i in range(len(s)):
char=s[i][0]        #get first char in each sentence
if char.isdigit():      #if 1st char is a digit (0-9)
    return i
```

Comment: Okay so that worked for my first test case but it isn't behaving right with others. For example: count_digit_leading_lines ("\t4G\nHz\n") → 0

Comment: Guessing you got it. :D

Comment: Still haven't figured out how to fix the error. I made sure char is a string so that isdigit works. I keep getting unexpected parsing error. Not sure why? @Kaushik

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
texts = ["1\n2\n\3", 'ABC\n123\n456\n555']


def _get_index_if_matching(text):
    split_text = text.split('\n')
    if split_text:
        for line_index, line in enumerate(split_text):
            try:
                num = int(line[0])
                if 0 < num < 9:
                    return line_index
            except ValueError:
                pass


for text in texts:
    print(_get_index_if_matching(text))
```

It will return `0` and then `1`

Comment: I am not supposed to call enumerate or print. Sorry I forgot to include that. I should only be using return and loops along with split

Answer (score -1):

You could change out your `return` statement for a `yield`, making your function a generator. Then you could get the indexes one by one in a loop, or make them into a list. Here's a way you could do it:

```
def count_digit_leading_lines(text):
    for index, line in enumerate(text.split('\n')):
        try:
            int(line[0])
            yield index
        except ValueError: pass

# Usage:
for index in count_digit_leading_lines(text):
    print(index)
# Or to get a list
print(list(count_digit_leading_lines(text)))
```

Example:

```
In : list(count_digit_leading_lines('he\n1\nhto2\n9\ngaga'))
Out: [1, 3]
```

Comment: Have to explicitly use return. No yield or print